# Moving the camera by 1.5m on the X and Z axis in Unity3D using the GearVR Controls

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

So I created a VR environment in Unity as a test. I have 4 spheres with Images projected inside each of the Spheres. What I would like to do is move the camera by 1.5m on the X and/or Z axis.

Sort of like Google StreetView. Does anyone know where I start? I'm new to C#/Unity Development.

[Top View of 3D Staging area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFAzK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by it being like Google Maps.

But if you are talking about simply moving the camera, attach a script to it, and in it, you write:

```
void Start() {
    transform.position = new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 1.5f);
}
```

Comment: Yes Sorry, It's meant to be Google StreetView! So I tired that link of code and I forgot to mention I'm using a GearVR headset so would like it to move in the X and/or Z axis via a click on the DPad at the side of the headset

Comment: I tired this <pre> using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveCam : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
 
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   transform.position = new Vector3 (1.5f, 0, 1.5f);
  }
 }
}
<code>